# How to get all subfolders from "root" recursively via SOAP from Exchange?

Tags: php, soap, exchange-server

After searching the web for hours you are my last hope:

I have to build a system which reads sent and incoming mails from a Microsoft Exchange Server. I found the following script for that:
Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP (Heartspring)
https://github.com/Heartspring/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP

The existing get_messages() function returns all messages for a folder, for example "inbox". So far everything is clear. My problem starts when I want to get all messages from "sent" - Folder - i've tried many words, from "send" to "Sent Items"; without any result (mailbox not available)

My idea was to get all subfolders for the folder "root" and wrote this:

```
include "init.php";

$ec = new ExchangeClient();
$ec->init("bambullis@123.de", "", NULL, "https://amxprd3610.outlook.com/EWS/Services.wsdl");

$folders = $ec->get_subfolders("root"); 

foreach($folders as $folder) {

    print_r($folder); 

}
```

This is what I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [FolderId] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => AAAeAGJhbWJ1bGxpc0BzdHVrZSbi5kZQAuAAAAAABw352p5E4yS5voYF9ELBmiAQBXYPdO6NZAQ6T9C3xviT7xAAAAC1iXAAA=
            [ChangeKey] => AQAAABYAAABXYPdO6NZAQ6T9C3xviAALNCey
        )

    [DisplayName] => Oberste Ebene des Informationsspeichers
    [TotalCount] => 0
    [ChildFolderCount] => 16
    [UnreadCount] => 0
)
```

(I know that FolderId->Id is base64 encoded, I've modified the string above for security reasons ;o))

Now I tried to list the subfolders for this directory (I added a mailbox to see, if the value "ChildFolderCount" will change, it does):

```
...
print_r($folder); 

print_r($ec->get_subfolders($folder->FolderId->Id)); 
...
```

This is the error I get: 
The request failed schema validation: The 'Id' attribute is invalid

What did I do wrong? How to get all subfolders from "root" recursively? Thanks to this lovely guy who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EWS-PHP [get_subfolders](https://github.com/Heartspring/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP/blob/master/lib/ExchangeClient.php#L442) method uses by default a [TraversalType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/exchangewebservices.folderquerytraversaltype%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) "**Shallow**", so it searches **only the identified folder** and returns only the folder IDs for items that have not been deleted.
To search in **all subfolders** of the identified parent folder and return only the folder IDs for items that have not been deleted you should use the "**Deep**" TraversalType.
For example:

```
<?php

include "init.php";

class myExchangeClient extends ExchangeClient {
    public function get_subfolders_deep($ParentFolderId = "inbox", $Distinguished = TRUE) {
        $this->setup();

        $FolderItem = new stdClass();
        $FolderItem->FolderShape = new stdClass();
        $FolderItem->ParentFolderIds = new stdClass();

        $FolderItem->FolderShape->BaseShape = "Default";
        /* 
        **  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/exchangewebservices.folderquerytraversaltype(v=exchg.140).aspx 
        **  Deep Traversal: Searches in all subfolders of the identified parent folder and returns only the folder IDs for items that
        **  have not been deleted.
        */
        $FolderItem->Traversal = "Deep";

        if ($Distinguished) {
          $FolderItem->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new stdClass();
          $FolderItem->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = $ParentFolderId;
        } else {
          $FolderItem->ParentFolderIds->FolderId = new stdClass();
          $FolderItem->ParentFolderIds->FolderId->Id = $ParentFolderId;
        }

        $response = $this->client->FindFolder($FolderItem);

        if ($response->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->ResponseCode == "NoError") {
          $folders = array();

          if (!is_array($response->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->RootFolder->Folders->Folder)) {
              $folders[] = $response->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->RootFolder->Folders->Folder;
          } else {
              $folders = $response->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->RootFolder->Folders->Folder;
          }

          return $folders;
        } else {
          $this->lastError = $response->ResponseMessages->FindFolderResponseMessage->ResponseCode;
        }
    }
}

$ec = new myExchangeClient();
$ec->init("bambullis@123.de", "", NULL, "https://amxprd3610.outlook.com/EWS/Services.wsdl");

$folders = $ec->get_subfolders_deep("root");
echo "<pre>".print_r($folders,true)."</pre>\n";

?>
```

Anyway, looking at the [ExchangeClient](https://github.com/Heartspring/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP/blob/master/lib/ExchangeClient.php#L178) class source code, the FolderID for the sent items should be "**sentitems**".